# How to make redux-observable send multiple actions before and after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to write Epic for redux-observable. But I am having a problem (

`ON_EMPTY_FORM_STATE` action is executed before `.map(response => formSavedAction(response))` is executed.

How can I fix it? Basically what I am trying to get is:

1. Capture `FORM_SEND` action
2. Send Ajax request with payload
3. If i get 200 response from server then execute `formSavedAction(response)`
4. If i get 500 error then dispatch `{ type: ON_FORM_SUBMIT_ERROR }`
5. At the end (no matter what Ajax request returned) I want to  dispatch action `{ type: EMPTY_FORM_STATE }`

And here is my code:

```
const saveProductEpic = (action$, $store) =>
action$.ofType(SUBMIT_FORM)
    .mergeMap(action => ajax.post('http://localhost:9000/products', action.payload,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }))
    .map(response => formSavedAction(response))
    .catch(err => { $store.dispatch({ type: ON_FORM_SUBMIT_ERROR }) })
    .do(() => { $store.dispatch({ type: EMPTY_FORM_STATE }) })
```

The issue is that action `{ type: EMPTY_FORM_STATE }` is dispatched **Before**
and not after AJAX request.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: just remove `.do` block and add `$store.dispatch({ type: EMPTY_FORM_STATE })` to the two cases `.then` and `.catch`

Comment: Not working.... I am getting error 
TypeError: action$.ofType(...).mergeMap(...).map(...).then is not a function

Comment: can i know why do you use `.map` instead of `.then` in your code? and what http library you use?

Comment: Will it make any any difference if i use .then instead of .map? Iam using RX.Dom.Ajax

Answer (score 0):

The way redux-observable works is that the observable returned by the epic function is subscribed to in the middleware. Your observable must emit redux actions because the subscribe function is just: `action => store.dispatch(action)`

Because you are using store.dispatch in your epic directly, you are circumventing redux-observable and dispatching things out of order from what you're expecting.

To emit the actions in the order you are expecting you can do this:

```
action$.ofType(SUBMIT_FORM)
  .mergeMap(action => ajax.post('http://localhost:9000/products', action.payload,
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }))
  .map(response => formSavedAction(response))
  // Notice that catch is now returning the value by dropping the brackets.
  .catch(err => Observable.of({ type: ON_FORM_SUBMIT_ERROR }))
  // send whatever action has come through, and add the empty state action after it.
  .mergeMap(action => Observable.of(action, { type: EMPTY_FORM_STATE }))
```

Concept Demo: https://jsbin.com/focujikuse/edit?js,console

Comment: Yes--Please please please don't use store.dispatch https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/314

Comment: I have tried to handle epic your way, but something strange is going on..
It looks like actions   .map(response => formSavedAction(response)) 
and  mergeMap(action => Rx.Observable.from(action$, { type: ON_EMPTY_FORM_STATE })) 

are never executed at all... I added some logging to my reducer and it shows absolutely nothing.

Comment: Fixed a mistake in the last mergeMap; need to use of, not from. Try logging in the epic with .do(console.log) statements. If it isn't making it past the ajax request there is probably a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

```
const saveProductEpic = (action$, $store) => action$.ofType(SUBMIT_FORM)
.mergeMap((data) => Rx.Observable.concat(
    ajax.post(url, data.payload, params).mergeMap(
        (response) => Rx.Observable.of(formSavedAction(response)) )
        .catch(err => { $store.dispatch({ type: ON_FORM_SUBMIT_ERROR }) }),
    Rx.Observable.of({ type: ON_EMPTY_FORM_STATE })
    .delay(2000)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

`const saveProductEpic = (action$, $store) =>
action$.ofType(SUBMIT_FORM)
    .mergeMap(action => ajax.post('http://localhost:9000/products',action.payload,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
         .mergeMap(response => Observable.of(formSavedAction(response), 
                                             emptyFormStateAction()))
         .catch(err => Observable.of(
              formSubmitErrorAction(), 
              emptyFormStateAction())
          )
     );`

where emptyFormStateAction and formSubmitErrorAction are action creators.